# How to make fun String.reverce() Kotlin working?

Tags: string, function, kotlin

please I cant't understand what im doing wrong, Im new at programming. I want to print "player Name" and then print it in reverce. and it prints only normal Name. Please help. Thank you

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
val playerName = "Partisan"

println(playerName)

fun String.reverced(playerName:String) = playerName
return
print(playerName)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing a bit at what you're trying to do.

It seems like you wanted to call the `reversed()` function on your string. But the syntax you used is for *defining* a function, not *calling* it. You also have an extra call to `return` in there that will end your program before it prints the reversed string.

First of all, a String is immutable. When you reverse it, you are creating a new String, so you must assign it to a variable. However, you defined `playerName` as a read-only `val`, so it cannot be changed. So the first step is to change it to `var`.

Then to get a reversed version of your String, you can use `playerName.reversed()` and assign the result back to the variable. So your final code looks like this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    var playerName = "Partisan"

    println(playerName)

    playerName = playerName.reversed()

    println(playerName)

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I wish you the best. +100500 to your Karma. Yes, i just didn't understand how to write this function correctly. You opened my eyes, now I got it, thank you.